# Fill a WPF Context Menu Dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have a WPF context menu on a tray icon. What I need is to dynamically add Menu Items according to a collection binded in ViewModel.

What is the best approach?
I tried this

```
<ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RegisteredWindows}">
                <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Show/Hide All" Command="{Binding Path=HideShow}" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="{Binding Path=Quit}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
</ContextMenu>
```

but I can't see text, only blank rows...

****Solved. See my answer below.

Comment: Place a converter and check your getting the Values?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I have mistaken the "Name" Property of Window with "Title" property.

Changing the binding in

```
...{Binding Path=Title}
```

it works.